# Update array object in mongoose@6.10.0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The below are my schemas:

```
const itemSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    item:String
});

const listSchmema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    items:[itemSchema]
});

const List=mongoose.model("List", listSchmema);
const Item=mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema);
```

In the else block, I need to append the items array the List model. but it is not getting updated.
Please help.

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    var newItem=req.body.newItem;
    var listName=req.body.button;
    if(listName==="Today"){
        addItem(newItem);
        res.redirect("/");
    }else{
        List.updateOne({name:listName}, {$push:{items:newItem}});
        res.redirect("/"+listName);
        
    }
```

Appending the items array inside the list model.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your `newItem` is just a String value. While in the array `items` of `listSchmema` you're passing another **object** `itemSchema` with a field `item` of type String. So `newItem` must be defined as an object with the `req.body.newItem` as value of `item`.

Like this:

```
var newItem = new Item({ 
   item: req.body.newItem 
});
```

So your code should be updated as:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    var newItem = new Item({ 
        item: req.body.newItem 
    });
    var listName=req.body.button;
    if(listName==="Today"){
        addItem(newItem);
        res.redirect("/");
    }else{
        List.updateOne({name:listName}, {$push:{items:newItem}});
        res.redirect("/"+listName);
    }
}
```